# Route URL in constants file. Should I do it?

Tags: routes, svelte, sveltekit

I want know about best practices for web development.

I use sveltekit and I have many page. I'm not sure how i manage my route.

I should keep all path route in constants file.

```
//constants file

const PAGE_HOME = '/home';

const PAGE_PRODUCT = '/product'

.

.

.

//+page.svlete

<a href={PAGE_HOME}>click</>
```

or I should use it inline like this.

```
<a href="/home">click</a>
```

Sorry, I'm not good at English.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.